# Can I programatically close a windows phone 8 application in vb.net

Tags: windows-phone-8

How do I programatically close a windows phone 8 application in vb.net
on clicking a image

Comment: Application.Current.Terminate();

Answer (score 1):

On WP8 you can do it using

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

but it's not really recommended...